# JSON data handling on signup issue

Tags: ios, json, swift

When I sign up the user I get a status code 200 and a token:"" JSON back.
If user already exists then I get a status code 200 and html response instead of JSON. How should I handle this problem. Thanks in advance.

What I have done is -

```
switch httpResponse.statusCode {
    case 200:
        // 2. Create JSON object with data
        do {
            let jsonDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as? [String: AnyObject]
            print(jsonDictionary!)
            if let jsonDictionaryOne = jsonDictionary {
                let authToken = AuthToken(tokenDictionary: jsonDictionaryOne)
                completion(authToken)
            }
        } catch {
            print("Fetch failed: \((error as NSError).localizedDescription)")
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                let authToken = AuthToken(tokenDictionary: ["token":"none"])
                completion(authToken)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're already dealing with it one way - the inability to create a JSon parser object could be used to infer that the response is html, however that would be an incorrect inference if invalid JSon is returned.

So another way would be to examine the HTTP header content type, in one situation the header content type should indicate json and in the other html.